# Selecting a javascript drop down via selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is the javascript drop down from which I want to select the "All Resume" option via selenium webdriver:

```
<div id="resume_freshness_container">
<div class="dropdown_small_wrapper">
<div class="left">Last 6 Months</div>
                                <div class="right"><img class="clip_image" src="http://media.monsterindia.com/v2/recruiter/2.1/new_search/newlook_combined.png"></div>
                                <div class="clear_both"></div>
                                </div></div>
<script language="javascript">  
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){  createSingleSelectCombo({id:'selDay',valueVariableName:'day',tabindex:'62',label:"",preSelected:"180",replaceWithId:'resume_freshness_container',width:'216',heightOptions:'height:240px;overflow-y:auto',animateScroll:true,
                options:[{id:'1',values:"in last 1 day"},
                {id:'3',values:"in last 3 days"},               
                {id:'7',values:"in last 7 days"},               
                {id:'15',values:"in last 15 days"},             
                {id:'30',values:"in last 1 month"},             
                {id:'90',values:"in last 3 months"},                
                {id:'180',values:"in last 6 months"},               
                {id:'360',values:"in last 12 months"},              
                {id:'540',values:"in last 18 months"},
                {id:'9999',values:"All Resumes"},
                {id:'4-7',values:"4-7 days"},
                {id:'8-15',values:"8-15 days"},
                {id:'16-30',values:"16-30 days"},
                {id:'31-90',values:"1-3 months"},
                {id:'91-180',values:"3-6 months"},
                {id:'181-360',values:"6-12 months"},
                {id:'361-540',values:"12-18 months"},
                {id:'541-9999',values:"Only older than 18 months"}

                ]});


                borderTopSingleSelect({container:'resume_freshness_container',afterId:'10'});

            });


</script>
```

I have used the following code to select the dropdown and then select the required option:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("resume_freshness_container")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("All Resumes");
```

*I have also tried selecing it with id "selDay" but both the times it gave me the same exception that I have listed below*

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div"
```

*I am new to selenium so kindly help me out to know where I am going wrong *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you cannot approach it with `Select` class - it is specifically for `select->option` HTML structures.

You need to first locate the element with `id="selDay"`, click on it, locate the element with "All Resumes" text and click on it:

```
WebElement selDay = driver.findElement(By.id("selDay"));
selDay.click();

WebElement allResumes = selDay.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.=\"All Resumes\"]"));
allResumes.click();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and by doing it the way you said it works but even after calling "allResumes.click();" the value is not selected. It gets highlighted but on submitting the form the default value which is "in last 6 months" gets passed whereas i want "All Resumes" to be passed

Comment: I also checked "allResumes.isSelected()" which is returning "false"

Comment: @YatinGrover just a shot in the dark, can you repeat the click two times?

Comment: Yeah I tried it the same thing earlier. But it didn't work so changed my approach. Now I was sending "tab" key to reach to the desired element.